# Creating Unfuddle SVN repositories from QT Creator?

Tags: c++, svn, repository, qt-creator, unfuddle

I am writing an application that creates a default file structure for my projects so I don't have to create the folders for every new project. All the work to create these folders is done, however there are still some things that I'd like to improve.

Right now I create a new repository in Unfuddle first, check it out, run my application, then manually commit the newly created folders.

Is there a way to create a repository using the Unfuddle API INSIDE Qt Creator? This way all the work can be done from inside the application, saving some more time. If there is, how would I get started doing this? Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem after following: https://unfuddle.com/stack/docs/api/repositories/.